# Double array $lookup call preserving original structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to populate a double array object but in an aggregate so I am utilizing the `$lookup` function. The collection looks something like this:

```
{
  foo: [
    {
      bar: [
        {
          _id: ObjectId('63f508eedd2962118c37ea36')
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My lookup looks like:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "collection",
    localField: "foo.bar",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "foo.bar",
  },
}
```

which results in

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId('63f508eedd2962118c37ea36'),
        field1: "helloworld"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where what I actually want is

```
{
  foo: [
    {
      bar: [
        {
          _id: ObjectId('63f508eedd2962118c37ea36'),
          field1: "helloworld"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I want in an aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a *direct map* with `$lookup` for the nested array is not possible.

1. `$lookup` - Join the `collection` collection and return the `bars` array field.
2. `$set` - Set `foo` array.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate element in `foo` array.

   2.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterated `foo` element with the result of *2.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1. A document with a `bar` field which contains the result of *2.1.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1.1. `$map` - Iterate element in `bar` array.

   2.1.1.1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterated `bar` element with the result of *2.1.1.1.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1.1.1.1. `$first` - Get the first matching element from the `bars` array by `_id`s.
3. `$unset` - Remove `bars` array.

```
db.from.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "foo.bar._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "bars"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      foo: {
        $map: {
          input: "$foo",
          as: "foo",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$foo",
              {
                bar: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$foo.bar",
                    as: "bar",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$bar",
                        {
                          $first: {
                            $filter: {
                              input: "$bars",
                              cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                  "$$bar._id",
                                  "$$this._id"
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "bars"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AnjmCLXLj53)

Comment: Wow that is a crazy aggregate. Many thanks!

Comment: @borrimorri, you are welcome. Glad to see it helps! =D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be simpler to `$unwind` at `foo` level first, do the `$lookup` and `$group` back the result?

```js
db.from.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$foo"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "foo.bar._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "foo.bar"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      foo: {
        $push: "$foo"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0p3LtVReRc4)